# Neo4j Cypher Query to find recipes where I have all the ingredients and a sufficient quantity

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to write a query that will find recipes I can make based on 2 criteria. I need to have all the ingredients and I need to have a sufficient quantity of each ingredient.

I have a graph structure like this: [image]

I have recipe nodes with relationships to ingredients that specify the quantity of the ingredient I need. And I have Pantry node with relationships to ingredients that specify the quantity of the ingredient I actually have.

I am trying to use the following query, but it is not handling quantities correctly, so it is returning recipes even if I don't have enough of all the ingredients.

```
MATCH (p:Pantry)-[has:HAS]->(i:Ingredient)
WITH COLLECT(i) AS pantry_ingredients, COLLECT(has) AS pantry_quantity
MATCH (r:Recipe)-[requires:REQUIRED]->(i:Ingredient)

WITH pantry_ingredients, pantry_quantity, r, COLLECT(i) AS recipe_ingredients
WHERE ALL(x IN recipe_ingredients WHERE x IN pantry_ingredients AND EXISTS{
    MATCH (:Pantry)-[has:HAS]->(:Ingredient {name: x.name})<-[requires:REQUIRED]-(:Recipe)      
    WHERE has.quantity >= requires.quantity})
    
RETURN r
```

How can I modify this to correctly filter out recipes based on having the needed quantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query may work for your use case (assuming you only have one `Pantry`):

```
MATCH (:Pantry)-[has:HAS]->(i:Ingredient)<-[required:REQUIRED]-(r:Recipe)
WHERE has.quantity >= required.quantity
WITH r, COUNT(i) AS iCount
WHERE iCount = COUNT{ (r)-[:REQUIRED]->() }
RETURN r
```

It finds all ingredients in the pantry that have a sufficient quantity for any recipe, counts the number of such ingredients for each recipe, and efficiently filters for those recipes in which the sufficient-ingredient count equals the required-ingredient count.

Answer (score 0):

This returns all recipes that the Pantry has enough ingredients for:

```sql
MATCH (r:Recipe)
WHERE all(enough IN 
        COLLECT {
          MATCH (r)-[req:REQUIRED]->(i:Ingredient)
          RETURN EXISTS { 
            (i)<-[h:HAS]-(:Pantry) WHERE req.requires <= h.has
          }
        } WHERE enough) 
RETURN r
```